# Invalid Write of Size 8 at first line in class constructor

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm having trouble getting a simple class constructor to work.

```
// In XModule.h
class XModule
{
...
public:
  TXMHeader     header;     // module header
  TXMInstrument*    instr;      // all instruments (256 of them)
  TXMSample*        smp;        // all samples (256 of them, only 255 can be used)
  TXMPattern*       phead;      // all pattern headers (256 of them)
}
```

Module.cpp

```
// In XModule.cpp
....
XModule::XModule()
{
  // allocated necessary space for all possible patterns, instruments and samples
  phead = new TXMPattern[256]; // Line # 1882
  instr = new TXMInstrument[256];
  smp = new TXMSample[MP_MAXSAMPLES];

  memset(&header,0,sizeof(TXMHeader));

  if (instr)
    memset(instr,0,sizeof(TXMInstrument)*256);

  if (smp)
    memset(smp,0,sizeof(TXMSample)*MP_MAXSAMPLES);

  if (phead)
    memset(phead,0,sizeof(TXMPattern)*256);

}
....
```

Extractor.cpp

```
#include "Extractor.h"
#include "XModule.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  XModule* module = new XModule();
  SYSCHAR* fileName = "Greensleeves.xm";

  ...

  return 0;
}
```

When I run with valgrind I get the following error:

```
==21606== Invalid write of size 8
==21606==    at 0x408BD3: XModule::XModule() (XModule.cpp:1882)
==21606==    by 0x4012D8: main (Extractor.cpp:9)
==21606==  Address 0x64874f0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

The later in the line `memset(instr,0,sizeof(TXMInstrument)*256);` it zeroes out `phead`, `instr` and `smp`.

Stepping through with gdb revealed that `phead`, `instr`, and `smp` are set correctly, before that, but the addresses of the array pointers are within the area that new allocated for the `instr` array. Examining `&phead` revealed this to be true.

Why does new the call to `instr = new TXMInstrument[256];` assign memory space that is used for `phead`, `instr` and `smp` and what can I do to fix this or further diagnose the issue?

Comment: Although your code is really inadvisable, poor C++ in almost every line, it isn't wrong as such. The error must be elsewhere. What is line 1882?

Comment: I would also speculate that you're class is being constructed in invalid memory, possibly one past the end of an array of `XModule` objects.  That would explain your symptoms.  Show us the code near `main (Extractor.cpp:9)`

Comment: A write of size 8 implies that it's the assignment to `phead` that's invalid (i.e. the class itself is in invalid memory).  Can you provide a complete test case?

Comment: Here are links to the full source files: 
https://github.com/STRd6/Milky-Tracker/blob/49b0a897a731bb898ee545272d4998cb62e1523d/src/milkyplay/XModule.h

https://github.com/STRd6/Milky-Tracker/blob/49b0a897a731bb898ee545272d4998cb62e1523d/src/milkyplay/XModule.cpp

The project is MilkyTracker, a tool for creating sample based audio files. I'm trying to use a component of it to load XM files and extract data.

Comment: Link to full file Extractor.cpp: https://gist.github.com/2306661

Comment: @DanielXMoore: By "complete test case", I don't really mean "all of your original code", no one here is going to trawl through thousands of lines of code.  I mean a [minimal test case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @DanielXMoore: The places I thought to look are fine, I'm stumped.  You'll have to do a SSCCE/minimal testcase.

Comment: Ok, working on a minimal test case, may take a while because the project is pretty large and I'm unfamiliar with it. Any advice on extracting code for a minimal test case from large open source projects?

Comment: I've deleted half of XModule.cpp, reducing it to mostly what is described here, and it is not exhibiting the error. I'll keep adding pieces in until I pinpoint it. Thanks for the help thus far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out there were a bunch of #IFDEFs in the class definition, so when I was compiling my utility against the library built with the projects makefile it was using the source headers and thought the class had a different amount of properties, so they were not arranged in memory correctly and got crushed by the allocation of the arrays.

I solved it by not using the projects library, copying the source files to a new folder, and running `g++ *.cpp`.

Comment: Another option is to "clean" your build directory and rebuild the whole thing. Sometimes the build system fails to rebuild artifacts that should be rebuilt.